# How to use PageHeader on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am trying to create an application for my Ubuntu Phone, that should be run on my desktop machine (15.10), too.
It runs fine on my Ubuntu Phone (OTA 10), but when I try to run it on my desktop machine, it only says `PageHeader is not a type`.
What do I have to do to use PageHeader on desktop machines or what else should I use instead of that?

Thanks

Comment: as i understand it is a bug. i solve it by  runing this `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/ubuntu-sdk-dev/lib/`
`$ /usr/ubuntu-sdk-dev/bin/qmlscene Main.qml` . before that i had to install the ubuntu-sdk-dev package.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow with an new project, now it is not working with an QML+C++ project, it says my C++ lib was not installed.

Comment: i think that you need different command for qml+c++. i did it with qml.

Comment: You were right, but I only had to execute `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/ubuntu-sdk-dev/lib/`

Comment: after upgrading my desktop to 16.04 it's ok.

Comment: that sounds good, I'll do it later this week

Comment: I am running the Ubuntu SDK or Qt Creator 3.5.1 Based on Qt 5.6.0 (GCC 5.2.1 20151010, 64 bit) on Ubuntu 15.10. I have tried the above, but keep getting: 
Starting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene...
file:///home/tomas/Dropbox/Ubuntu-Touch/ubuntu-sdk/Test3/app/Main.qml:19 PageHeader is not a type 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene exited with code 255

Anything else I can try to fix this?